# Convergence of a series using Cauchy Condensation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I came across the following interesting problem while reading about convergence theorems:-

$Q$. Test the following series for convergence ($p$ and $q$ denote fixed real numbers and $0<q<p$).$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^p-n^q}$$

I used Cauchy Condensation theorem to try the problem. According to Cauchy Condensation theorem, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^na_{2^n}$ is convergent then the original series is also convergent.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac {2^n}{2^{np}-2^{nq}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{2^{n(q-1)}}\left(\frac 1{2^{n(p-q)}-1}\right)$$ After some finite $N$, $\forall n\ge N$, whatever the value of $p-q$, $n(p-q)>1$. Hence $$2^{n(p-q)}-1\ge 2^{n(p-q)-1}$$This shows that after $N$,$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac 1{2^{n(q-1)}}\left(\frac 1{2^{n(p-q)}-1}\right)\le \sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac 1{2^{n(q-1)}}\left(\frac 1{2^{n(p-q)-1}}\right)=\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac 2{2^{n(p-1)}}$$
Obviously the above expression is a GP and hence convergent if $p>1$ and divergent if $p<1$. Also before $N$ the sum is finite as $N$ is finite.

Am I right to conclude that the convergence of the series doesn't depend on $q$?

Comment: First, to use CCT you need the series' sequence to be monotone descending. Also, where does $\;\zeta(s)\;$, which is in the end of your post, enter in what you did before?

Comment: It does when $n \to \infty$. The sequence becomes $\zeta(p)$.

Comment: We can also show that the series' sequence is monotonically decreasing. $(n+1)^p-(n+1)^q>n^p-n^q\implies n^p(1+1/n)^p-1>n^q(1+1/n)^q-1\implies (1+1/n)^{p-q}>(1/n)^{p-q}$ which is true.

Answer (score 2):

Once  more, the *equivalents* makes it of the utmost simplicity. Note this is a series with positive terms, hence we can use equivalents. If$n>1$, and $q<p$, $\;n^p-n^q\sim_\infty n^p$, hence
$$\frac1{n^p-n^q}\sim_\infty\frac1{n^p},$$
which converges if $p>1$, which diverges if $\;0<p\le 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but could you point out the flaw in my arguments?

Comment: The final exponent should be $2^{n(p-1)-1}$, not $\;2^{np-2}$.

Comment: Oh thank you very much.....